# Different slashes in web application paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Why if I need to check if a folder exists on the web server I need to use backslashes in the path string:

```
 if (Directory.Exists(@"~\assets\images\gallery\thumbnails"))
```

while to load the image I need to use slashes?

```
 new WebImage("~/assets/images/gallery/thumbnail/name.jpg")
```

What's rule behind this?

Thanks.

Comment: Filesystem paths on Windows: backslashes; URLs: forward slashes. Also keep in mind the tilde character `~` has no special meaning in file paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Directory.Exists` is a check against file system, which on Windows follows [Windows path specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (the link is not exactly "specification," but will do for the purpose) which has `\` as directory separator.  On *nix systems, however, it would take `/` as directory separator.  Thus, one should use [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for correctness and interoperability.

`WebImage` takes a URL reference (`~` notwithstanding) and follows [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) which defines `/` as segment separator.

The two, while appearing similar, are different and (mostly) unrelated concepts.

Answer (score 0):

For URLs you use forward slashes.  In file paths in Windows you use backslashes.  The first path is to a location on the hard drive.  The second path is to a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe WebImage refers to a virtual path, as used in URLs and referred to by the browser (for example).
Directory refers to actual physical directories on the server.
Windows uses backslash for physical directories.
URL conventions use slash for virtual paths.